# Crashlytics isn't reporting any foreground OOMs

Tags: ios, out-of-memory, crashlytics

I've created OOM crashes by growing an infinitely large NSArray of NSStrings, and I've even tried calling `exit(0)` just to make it look like an OOM. While these things to have worked to terminate the app unexpectedly, I don't see any OOMs reported on Crashlytics and it doesn't call the delegate callback, `crashlyticsDidDetectReportForLastExecution:`, on the next run of the app. I'm running the app on a real device that is not connected to a simulator, and any other kind of crash/error it reports fine. Does anyone have any idea what the issue might be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. We chatted over Fabric support as well, but to clarify for all. OOMs are detected on the server, but are processed in batch at the end of a current UTC day and will be visible in your Fabric Crashlytics' dashboard starting the next UTC day after our processing completes.

Comment: What about Firebase Crashlytics? I can see no OOM reports there.

Comment: Right now, Firebase Crashlytics doesn't have OOM reporting. It's not planned to be added at this moment.