# iOS Firebase Crashlytics: Out Of Memory (OOM) Reporting

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

I use Firebase Crashlytics for crash reporting. Recently I got some Out Of Memory (OOM) crashes on my iOS device. So I'm trying to find any reports in Firebase Crashlytics console but there are no results. At the same time I can see reported data about OOM crashes in Fabric Crashlytics console but it's deprecated.

Does Firebase Crashlytics support reporting OOM issues?

I looked through Firebase docs, googled, but I didn't find any information related to this.

Also, I ran into this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43783817/4891132 where it's mentioned that was not planned to add to Firebase.

Is something changed here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, Crashlytics answered in [twitter](https://twitter.com/Arzhannikov_A/status/1073194994134065152) that currently they don't support reporting OOM crashes. Also there is no information about plans for implementing this.